# Help with Arrays and the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps api function place markers which I'm using from the tutorial found here:[Google Maps API with JQuery](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/google-maps-api-jquery)

By any means, I had to modify the javascript to account for my application. I'm pulling markers from an XML file like before, though this time I'm getting multiple requests, and multiple standard deviation, time to serve, and means for these requests. I've set up the XML to have these with a counter appended to the tag, but it looks like it's not rendering into an array correctly.

To note, I've never used Javascript, and am mostly flying by the seat of my pants on this, so if it's an atrocity of Javascript, feel free to let me know, the entire generation of the XML is in Python.

Sample of the XML: (I apologize, I don't know how to show < or > on stack overflow without it simply hiding it as a tag. Around each "markers" "marker" "name" "requestX" "timetoserveX" etc. is the < and > for tags in XML.

> markers
>       marker
>       name Simpletown, CA /name
>       request0 /resource/ /request0
>       timetoserve0 .001 Seconds to serve request /timetoserve0
>       mean0 .5309 Mean in seconds /mean0
>       std_dev0 .552 Standard Deviation in Seconds /std_dev0
>       request1 /resource2/ /request1
>       timetoserve1 0.015626 Seconds to serve request /timetoserve1
>       mean1 0.0011 Mean in seconds /mean1
>       std_dev1 0.004465 Standard Deviation in Seconds /std_dev1
>       /marker
>   /markers

```
MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
$.get(filename, function(xml){
    $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
        var count = 0;
        var requeststring = 'request' + Integer.toString(count)
        var request = new Array();
        var timetoserve = new Array();
        var mean = new Array();
        var std_dev = new Array();
        var timetoservestring = 'timetoserve' + Integer.toString(count);
            var meanstring = 'mean' + Integer.toString(count);
        var std_devstring = 'std_dev' + Integer.toString(count);
        while ($(this).find(requeststring).text()){
            timetoservestring = 'timetoserve' + Integer.toString(count);
            meanstring = 'mean' + Integer.toString(count);
            std_devstring = 'std_dev' + Integer.toString(count);
            request[count] = $(this).find(requeststring).text();
            timetoserve[count] = $(this).find(timetoservestring).text();
            mean[count] = $(this).find(meanstring).text();
            std_dev[count] = $(this).find(std_devstring).text();
            count++;
            requeststring = 'request' + Integer.toString(count)
        }
        // create a new LatLng point for the marker
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

        // extend the bounds to include the new point
        MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: MYMAP.map
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var html = ""
        for (i=0;i<count;i++){
            html=html+'<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+request[i]+'<br />'+timetoserve[i]+'<br />'+mean[i]+'<br />'+std_dev[i]+<br />;
            //var html='<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+request+'</strong.><br />'+timetoserve+'</strong.><br />'+mean+'</strong.><br />'+std_dev;
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
        });
        MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
    });
});
}
```

With the updates, it's not longer having the array issues it looks like, even though I am getting the map to render at this point. The "Show Markers" button is not populating the map with markers. Running FireBug with this seems to only spew endless amounts of "Break on error" hits and warnings for jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var request[count] = $(this).find(requeststring).text();
        var timetoserve[count] = $(this).find(timetoservestring).text();
        var mean[count] = $(this).find(meanstring).text();
        var std_dev[count] = $(this).find(std_devstring).text();
```

to

```
        request[count] = $(this).find(requeststring).text();
        timetoserve[count] = $(this).find(timetoservestring).text();
        mean[count] = $(this).find(meanstring).text();
        std_dev[count] = $(this).find(std_devstring).text();
```

-assuming these are the arrays that are not working correctly for you.

If I may make a suggestion (RE your comment this morning):

```
    while ($(this).find(requeststring).text()){
        //...omitted 
    }
```

if you were to rename all your tags to the same thing and give them an id attribute (which is valid in xml) you can do this:

```
    var requests = $(this).find('request');
    var timetoserves = $(this).find('timetoserve');
    // etc...
    for (var i=0; i<requests.length; i++) {
        request[i] = requests.eq(i).text();
        timetoserve[count] = timetoserves.eq(i).text();
        //etc...
    }
```

which would probably provide better performance.

Comment: Was that the solution? (took me a second to notice as well)

Comment: Wow... seriously? I can't believe I double initialized the variables. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Updated the issue, I'm actually getting "Google is not Defined" now. :(

Comment: Wait, is the error in your file or in a file on the google server? If it's on google's side, make sure you are including the google maps api js properly, and before your code tries to access it.

Comment: The thing that is puzzling me is that I'm using the exact code posted in the tutorial I referenced. That tutorial code works, though when I update to my XML, and using my MYMAP.placemarkers function, that is when it's not rendering the map. It's only rendering the button.

Comment: Nevermind the Google is not Defined, it's actually now simply not performing the "Show Markers" when clicked. Or at least, visually, no markers are placed.

Comment: Is that all the xml you're getting in? Because lat and lon are not included, and that would cause nulls to pop up and errors to be caused.

Comment: Worked with my wife last night, the while loop was actually returning empty strings which I assumed would work like Python, unfortunately an empty string is NOT false in JS, so it kept itself in an infinite loop. adding ! = "" got it out of the loop and I'm now faced with JQuery's recursion giving me a Stack Overflow. Going to look into an alternate solution at this point.

Comment: I've changed the python to instead do one line for the output that contains the name/time/mean/std_dev into one tag. So it looks for Marker, then MarkerText within that tag. This is still giving overflow errors, so at this point I'm thinking of looking into just porting this to Django and using Python. Which I am more familiar with. I've never used JQuery before and it seems to just give me recursion errors.